# What is the best way to make my puzzle 8 project better?

Tags: vb.net

I have this code for a puzzle8 project:

```
Private Sub Button10_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
        Dim indexrand As Integer
        Dim pos As Integer
        Dim m As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        For j = 0 To 100
            pos = 0
            indexrand = R.Next(0, 9)
            For i = indexrand To 8
                array.Insert(0, array(i + pos))
                pos += 1
            Next
            m = 9 - indexrand
            Do While m > 0
                array.RemoveAt(array.Count - 1)
                m -= 1
            Loop
        Next
```

I made a loop to shuffle them and it worked perfectly. Then I wanted it to give every button a value, so I did this:

```
Button1.Text = array(0)
Button2.Text = array(1)
Button3.Text = array(2)
Button4.Text = array(3)
Button5.Text = array(4)
Button6.Text = array(5)
Button7.Text = array(6)
Button8.Text = array(7)
Button9.Text = array(8)`
```

However, I have a problem here since the value 9 won't turn into "", so I did this:

```
If Button1.Text = 9 Then
    Button1.Text = ""

ElseIf Button2.Text = 9 Then
    Button2.Text = ""

ElseIf Button3.Text = 9 Then
    Button3.Text = ""

ElseIf Button4.Text = 9 Then
    Button4.Text = ""

ElseIf Button5.Text = 9 Then
    Button5.Text = ""

ElseIf Button6.Text = 9 Then
    Button6.Text = ""

ElseIf Button7.Text = 9 Then
    Button7.Text = ""

ElseIf Button8.Text = 9 Then
    Button8.Text = ""

ElseIf Button9.Text = 9 Then
    Button9.Text = ""
End If `
```

This does work. However, my problem is it's a whole lot of `If` statements. Is there any way to loop this without typing all these ifs?

Comment: You can loop through all buttons on your forms with `For Each ctrl As Control In controls`. Then Check if `TypeOf ctrl Is Button`. Then you just need to do your code.

Comment: @nbadaud It's a nice suggestion, but you should expand further, since this code is triggered by a button that shouldn't be changed.

Comment: sorry as I said before I'm new to vb.net, so what you're trying to tell me isn't so clear .. ! anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: @ProGrammer Noticed ! I tried to give a better answer below.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict: `If Button1.Text = 9` is comparing an number to a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, **turn on Option Strict**! That done, try this:

```
Dim Buttons() As Button = {Button1, Button2, Button3, Button4, Button5, Button6, Button7, Button8, Button9}
For i As Integer = 0 To array.Length - 1
    Buttons(i).Text = If(array(i) = 9," ",array(i).ToString())
Next
```

This replaces BOTH the 2nd and 3rd code snippets in the question. We can have even more fun to include the first snippet like this:

```
Public Function Shuffle(Of T)(ByVal items As IList(Of T)) As IList(Of T)
    Static rand As New Random()
    For i As Integer = items.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
        Dim j As Integer = rand.Next(i + 1)
        Dim temp As T= items(i)
        items(i) = items(j)
        items(j) = temp
    Next
    Return items
End Function

Private Sub Button10_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click 
    Dim Buttons() As Button = {Button1, Button2, Button3, Button4, Button5, Button6, Button7, Button8, Button9}
    Dim values = Shuffle(Enumerable.Range(0, 9).ToList())
    For i As Integer = 0 To values.Length - 1
        Buttons(i).Text = If(values(i) = 9," ",values(i).ToString())
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: +5000 for using Option Strict!

Comment: well as a beginner to vb the first sample you gave I honestly understand it, and it was a better way to use the find 9. but the other sample you gave, to tell the truth, I'm not sure what you've done at all.. ! anyway thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

This code will work :

```
Private Sub Button10_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
    For Each ctrl As Control In Controls
        ' Check if the control is a button and not the Button10
        If TypeOf ctrl Is Button And ctrl.Name <> "Button10" Then
            ' Check if the current button's text is 9                
            If ctrl.Text = "9" Then
                ctrl.Text = ""
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

By the way, I am not sure that the condition `If ctrl.Text = "9"` is the best way to do this.

Comment: it actually worked but, would you please explain what you've done here? because I'm still not sure why it worked

Comment: @Kamal When the click event of the Button10 is fired, this code loop through each control of your form. If the current control is a Button and it's name is not "Button10", I verify that the current button text is 9. If this condition is true,  I set the current button's text to "".

Comment: @Kamal No problem ! Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you to solve your problem.